# Percentile values of a raster file are nan

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, statistics

I am trying to extract some statistics from all rasters in a directory and saving them into a CSV file using Python. The script works, but the results for all percentile values are always nan. Any clue why this is happening?

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
import csv
import numpy as np
import argparse


def getStatsFromRaster(input_tif_dir, band_num, output_file):

    # Get a list of all tif files in the input folder
    tif_files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_tif_dir) if f.endswith('.tif')]
    band_int = int(band_num)

    # Initialize a list to hold the results
    results = []

    # Loop through each tif file
    for tif_file in tif_files:
        # Open the raster file
        ds = gdal.Open(os.path.join(input_tif_dir, tif_file))

        # Get the raster band
        band = ds.GetRasterBand(band_int)
        nodata = band.GetNoDataValue()

        if nodata is None:
            print('Nodata value is not present')
        # Check if nodata is present
        else:
            print('Nodata value is:', nodata)

        # Get the statistics for the band
        stats = band.GetStatistics(0, 1)

        # Get the percentiles for the band
        data = band.ReadAsArray()
        # data[data == nodata] = np.nan
        p1, p5, p25, p50, p75, p95, p99 = np.percentile(data, [1, 5, 25, 50, 75, 95, 99])

        # Add the results to the list
        results.append([tif_file] + stats + [p1, p5, p25, p50, p75, p95, p99])

    # Write the results to a CSV file
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(
            ['File Name', 'Minimum', 'Maximum', 'Mean', 'Standard Deviation', 'P1', 'P5', 'P25', 'P50', 'P75', 'P95',
             'P99'])
        writer.writerows(results)

    print('Results written to', output_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='It gets the statistics of a raster file'
    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--input-tif-dir',
        default=None
    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--band',
        default=None
    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--output-file',
        default=None
    )

    args = aparser.parse_args()
    getStatsFromRaster(args.input_tif_dir, args.band, args.output_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing **np.percentile** by **np.nanpercentile** made the script work.